# Using Sklearn Pipeline with new features in the test set (text classification)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, text-classification

I have a small number of labeled text samples that I want to use to predict the labels of a much larger sample. I have trained a classifier I'm happy with, but when I go to predict on the larger sample I see that the feature set is much larger. In the training sample there are about 10K words, in the test sample there are about 50k words.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf_rf = Pipeline([
    ("vect", CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),
    ("clf", RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True, n_jobs=36, n_estimators=150))
])
clf_rf = clf_rf.fit(X, y)
```

And when I go to predict on the larger set I get the following error:

```
y_score = clf_rf.predict(X_score)
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 10000 and input n_features is 50000
```

How can I use my classifier pipeline on the larger sample?

Comment: My temporary fix is to capture a set of all words in the original set, and then filter out any words not in that set. Seems like there should be an "in-pipeline" way to address this, but for posterity that's my current solution.